# need help in identifying bathroom sink faucet set

Tags: plumbing, faucet

This set is most likely 30 years old. (We also have the matching tub set.) I'd like to replace all of the faucet innards or replace the entire set.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

[image: see picture please]
[image: side view]
[image: cartridge]
[[image: broken piece from inside full assembly[4]]
[image: full assembly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll ante up with American Standard. Remove the top stem(s) under the handle(s), take it to the store & match up a replacement. Keep the old stem(s) until you're good & sure everything's proper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37252/discussion-between-mts-and-iggy).

Comment: It seems to be working although that Y piece did cause me some problems. If I don't screw in the cartridge very tight so that it pushes down on the Y piece the tap does not full shut off. So I am convinced that I should change the whole cartridge assembly if American Standard can supply a replacement. I'm planning on calling them in the morning.

Once again, thanks very, very much for your help and encouragement.

Comment: Sounds good from 1-side. But, we now know that the faucet is & has been broken internally. Given that their 3885 so closely matches what you have, I'd opt for a whole new faucet. You can try a dry-fit & see if you can just re-use the old handles & escutcheons. Just an idea.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. My intention is to use the old escutcheons and handles. We'll see.

Comment: Well, the plot thickens, unfortunately. I just called American Standard, sent them a picture and they tell me it is not their faucet! Any ideas on how to identify it?

Comment: Yeah, like they know :) They probably made it though, American Standard owned & made the market for decades. But, it really doesn't matter. No manufacturer's stuff necessarily fits from model to model or generation to generation. Take the handles & escutcheons with you to the store & eyeball or test fit on the display models or un-taped boxes & get a few different replacements to try out. But, I'd still just go brand new for both the sink & tub. You know you can get the same or better look & you're now an expert installer.